# Android Studio - NullPointerException warning on setOnClickListener

Tags: android, android-studio

This question is not about a real problem. More of an interrogation. Since Android Studio 2.1 Preview 2, I have a really weird behavior. On all my setOnClickListener, I have a warning on it telling me that the function may produce a NullPointerException. It does it on Button/LinearLayout/TextView... I find it really strange and wonder if there has been any changes in Android/Android Studio that I couldn't find on Google.

Here is a screen of my code with the warning :
[image]
Thanks for any enlightenment.

Comment: If you add the `if (bConnect != null)` check before setting its listener, the warning should disappear, does it?

Comment: Nvi9's answer makes sense to me. This problem is typical in Fragments when the user tries to abuse the app. Views do not get initialized and any methods accessed for non initialized views will result in a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: it shows that due to edit text you have in onClickListener. Using getText on edit text can certainly give null pointer exception if you get it without typing anything in edittext

Comment: and in your checkEmail method you should pass string and not edittext

Comment: @nvi9 Indeed the if(bConnect != null) makes the warning disappear... I find it really odd. I tried to put a bConnect.setBackgroundColor() after the setOnClick and got no warning, but if i put it before, the warning goes on the setBackgroundColor and disappear from the setOnClick. So I have to put an if before using any component gotten from the xml ? So much for lightening the code... Thanks again for your answers !

Comment: You should post code in your question above.

Comment: @Kazuya That's because only first null access would result in NPE. Second one would not be reached at all.

Comment: @VivekMishra EditText getText does not return null. TextView constructor sets initial text to empty string, and setText method checks for null.

Comment: I am not saying it is returning null . I am saying the warning is for that only that your edit text might return null. If you put it inside try catch it will not show that warning